# TimeoutException using Google Chrome in headless mode through Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait, google-chrome-headless, timeoutexception

I wanted to use headless mode in my python selenium project, and I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TimeoutException
```

The last traceback was on line 26, and it was also the first line after succesfully opening a website. Here is the line in question:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class=' css-1hy2vtq']"))).click()
```

---

## What I've tried to solve it:

I've tried adding arguments to the chrome options, I've tried switching up the first line and so I found out that waiting for an *element_to_be_clickable()* does not work but *find_element(By)*, does (well in this case at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *classnames* i.e. `css-1hy2vtq`, etc are dynamically generated and is bound to change sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

You need to consider any of the other attributes which is ***static*** in nature. Example:

```
//button[text()='Click Me']
```

Comment: update: When I remove the class and just have the static attributes it doesn't seem to recognize it

Comment: Try any other _**static**_ attribute or the parent element with unique attribute.